# Eclipse javadoc configuration (for own project)

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

**We can configure a library's (jar) javadoc in a Project in Eclipse by:** 
   - Opening the Preferences window 
   - Select the Java Build Path (menu) 
   - Open the Libraries tab
   - Select a jar and Edit the Javadoc location.

If you have a Javadoc view opened (in Eclipse) whenever you select an object from that specific library you will be able to display the Javadoc content inside the window. I find it quite useful.

**My question is:**
If you generate your project's javadoc, is it possible to configure its location in the project and display the content (the same way as mentionned above)?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as soon as you have generated your Javadoc for your project inside Eclipse. Any Javadoc content from a selected object will appear in the Javadoc view.